# How to get API caller detail info in .NET Core 2.1?

Tags: .net, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-apicontroller

How to get possible detail caller info whoever consuming my API in .NET Core 2.1?

Here is how I designed API endpoint:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your description, I suggest you could use httpcontextaccessor's httprequest context to get the client information.

If you want to use this in your controller, you should firstly register the startup.cs.

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddHttpContextAccessor();

        services.AddControllers();
        services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
        {
            c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "CoreAPINormalIssue", Version = "v1" });
        });
    }
```

Then inside the controller, you should use below codes:

```
    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;

    public WeatherForecastController(ILogger<WeatherForecastController> logger, IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
    {
        _logger = logger;
        _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
    }
```

Then inside the controller:

```
// Get the client IP address.
var re =  _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Connection.RemoteIpAddress;
```

More details, you could refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.connectioninfo?view=aspnetcore-5.0).